# HP Fortify Rule Suppression Attribute C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, fortify

Is there a way to suppress or address HP Fortify findings using attributes in C#?  An existing analog would be the SuppressMessage attribute in the Visual Studio Code Analysis tool.  (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244717(v=vs.110).aspx)

I want to use a C# attribute, like [SuppressMessage(..)] to address issues so I don't have to manually address these issues using the Fortify Tool.  Using the tool becomes rather tedious when creating new baselines or when sharing code.

Comment: When you try `SurpressMessage` using the Fortify tool; does it respect that attribute?

Comment: George, the suppress button in the Fortify tool works, but does not add attributes to the code.  Instead the suppression is stored in the .fpr file. When a new baseline is created, we have to re-suppress everything.  My hope is that by storing the suppression info in the code as an attribute, duplicate work can be eliminated.  Also, we want to do more than just suppress, we want to use attributes to address findings as "Not an Issue" or other using C# attributes.

Comment: Wouldn't that be like giving a burglar an invisibility cloak? :P

Comment: @DavidPeden good call. If they had the code and Fortify they could find the same info easily enough. But this solution would make things a bit easier for someone with bad intentions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried merging your first FPR into the new baseline? That will bring the suppressions into the current baseline so you don't have to repeat the analysis. That's how suppression was designed to work. You can also achieve this by using Software Security Center.

You can also try posting Fortify issues to their online forum at https://protect724.hp.com. The support group monitors those forums.

Comment: We were told this would start to breakdown during a larger code restructuring effort like a big upgrade.  Hence the desire to put our hard work into a bit more durable format, like attributes in the code.  It was suggested if we worked in smaller chunks that the merges may be more durable.

Comment: As long as you are scanning often and merging often, this approach will work fine. Where it can start to break down is if you do a scan of an app and then do another scan where a large amount of the code has changed. That may cause the issue IDs used by Fortify to track issues across scans could change. Even in that cause, it's better to deal with some issue overlap instead of starting from scratch.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, and that is what I'm probably going to do, but I would still like to know how this can be done in code.  I was told it was possible, but cannot find any docs for doing it.

Comment: Fortify has annotations for Java, but not .NET. If you look in the Samples/advanced folder in the SCA installation there is some example code for Java Annotations.

Comment: Hi Eric. I have started [a thread in the Fortify community forums](https://community.hpe.com/t5/Fortify-Software-Security-Center/Net-quot-SuppressMessageAttribute-quot-and-Fortify-warnings/td-p/6938769) about this. Could you take a look there?